# Why are all images from my PC copied into One Drive?

Tags: onedrive

I was looking through my photos on One Drive and noticed that every jpg on my PC has been copied up to the cloud.  This is wasting a tremendous amount of space and I am afraid that deleting them will delete them from my PC.  These are not only jpgs but icon images from every app on my PC.  How did I manage to do this and how do I fix it?